# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 186 but received input with shape (None, 180)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJZbL.png)

----------------------------------------------

```
import IPython.display as ipd
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(186, input_shape=(186,), activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=30)
```

Comment: Could you upload the code?

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your `X_train` is `(None,180)` but you are giving input of shape `(None,186)` to your dense layer.
Change

```
model.add(Dense(186, input_shape=(186,), activation = 'relu'))
```

to:

```
model.add(Dense(186, input_shape=(180,), activation = 'relu'))
```